# MongoDB: Compare Documents by Date

Tags: mongodb

I have one collection in MongoDB:

```
{
    date: new Date(2015, 01, 01), //Only year, month and days.
    name: 'Some Unique Name',
    price: '15.055'
}
```

For each day I have thousands of records in one collection. The data is almost always the same, except that some items were added, removed or updated. I want to retrieve those changes to output collections.

Maybe this is not a good for MongoDB. Maybe is better to use SQL, where this task is trivial.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For this kind of stuff, you might consider using something like BigQuery which is column-oriented datastore. That allows you to access all the data for the particular column and distribute all the processing work without having to skip through rows (SQL) or documents (Mongo).

Comment: We need more detail. The data is almost always the same as what? The previous day? Is it one collection per day or just one collection receiving thousands of records for each day, for many days? What do you want to do with the changes? What do you want to do with the documents besides find changes?

Comment: The data is consistent for each day, so it duplicates huge amount of data. That's why I'm not sure whether is a good idea to store it raw or compress somehow. I didn't think to split collection yet, at least now I see no problem with it. Basically I want to describe changes to the user, a bit similar to google analytics. You can select a period between days and see what was changed/removed/added